# Make slider work in any browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, transition

I have taken the following code for an image slider from [codepen](http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl). Now i want to make it fit the center of any browser window leaving 5% space on the left and right. I tried taking the `$(window).width();` in a variable and assigning it to the css value `width` but i am getting erratic outputs.

My code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    setInterval(function() {
        moveRight();
    }, 5500);
    //$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
    $('#slider ul').css({
        width: sliderUlWidth,
        marginLeft: -slideWidth
    });
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: +slideWidth
        }, 750, function() {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: -slideWidth
        }, 750, function() {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
    $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
        moveLeft();
    });
    $('a.control_next').click(function() {
        moveRight();
    });
});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
}

#slider ul {
   position: inherit;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

}

#slider ul li {
  position: inherit;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px; // I want to change this
  height: 500px; // and this
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image:url(PSG.jpg);background-size:100%;"></li>
        <li style="background-image:url(STUD.jpg);background-size:100%;"></li>
        <li style="background-image:url(EVERTON.jpg);background-size:100%;"></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Could you define "erratic outputs" more precisely please?

Comment: The images do not fit the slider width properly and as soon i click left or right the corresponding image just flashes for a second and goes away leaving a blank gray space in the slider. Also after refreshing the page the starting image seems to be offset a bit outside the slider boundaries.

Comment: Try to give it a 'max-width: 1200px'.  Have you tried using your html file for the slider width?  Try using inside your html < ul style="max-width: 1200px" >.  See if it will make a difference at least in establishing the width.

Comment: Also, instead of using %, give your image a size.

Comment: Setting max width in html made the slider disappear. I used % to make it somewhat resolution independent. Earlier i had used px but the slider appeared smaller on higher resolution screens on other machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the following adjustments to your css file.  It worked well on my browser.  Make sure you use large images in the size of your large monitor screen and as large as you want them to appear inside your slider.  For now the norm for full screen sliders are images at the width of 1900px.

Hope it works for you.

```
 #slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;  /* take out margin-top. This will give 20px margin to the top and center your slider */
  width: 90%;  /* less than 100% width gives margins to the sides */
  height: 500px;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: inherit;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;  /* this will center your images inside #slider */
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;   /* this will fill the container of your slider  */
  height: 500px;  /* depends on the actual size of your images */
 }
```